# LicenseChecker is slow in emulator

Tags: android, google-play

When the emulator hits the line below it takes 10 seconds + to complete.  Does anyone else have this problem?

```
mChecker = new LicenseChecker( this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this, new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)), BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
```

Comment: I haven't tried this specifically, but the emulator is slow in general.  Try it out on some phones.

Comment: 5 seconds on my actual phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up putting the initial call to the setup into a background task.  whenever its finished then it will go on and check the license.